# Haskell `linesCut` function - why is the last line causing a type problem, and how can I fix it?

Tags: haskell

```
linesCut :: String -> [String]
linesCut "" = [""]
linesCut (x:xs)
   |x == '\n' = [""] ++ linesCut xs
   |otherwise = x: (head (linesCut xs))
```

I would like to understand the type problem caused by compiling such a function. Why does the last line have a type problem?

I have the impression that it is a `Char` and that `(head (linesCut xs))` a string but is it really the case?

Comment: When your compiler throws an error and you seek debugging help, please include the error message within your question, see [mre].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
linesCut :: String -> [String]
linesCut "" = [""]
linesCut (x:xs)
   |x == '\n' = [""] ++ linesCut xs
   |otherwise = x: (head (linesCut xs))
```

Let's check the types for all the main portions of your code:

```
(x:xs) :: String
x :: Char
xs :: String
linesCut xs :: [String]
head (linesCut xs) :: String
(x : head (linesCut xs)) :: String
```

So, the last expression is a `String`, but `linesCut` has to return a `[String]` (the first line, the type signature, says that), and that causes a type error.

You probably intended to write something like

```
| otherwise = (x : head (linesCut xs)) : ....
```

To simplify your code, it's usually better to avoid `head` and `tail` and use pattern matching instead. Here's a hint

```
| otherwise = (x : ys) : ....
  where (ys : yss) = linesCut xs
```

Here `ys` is the first string in the recursive call, while `yss` is the list of strings after the first was taken.